# Showing JSON data using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('http://application.deckmonitoring.com/data/latest.json?target_type=node&target_id=1&token=12345678901234567890');

    $string = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    print_r($string); # for reference

?>


<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><?php if (!empty($string)) {
                foreach ($string as $key => $value) {
                    echo $value['data_type'];
                }
            } else {
                echo 'There is nothing here';
            }
             ?>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

What I am trying to do is get some JSON data from the url and create a foreach loop that goes through the items in the array. I have converted the raw data into an associative array . What I am having trouble with is that I do not know what I would use for a key to reference each object. I've tried a couple of things and experimented using the keys it lists in the raw data. Some help, or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

This is what I am getting from the line that says I am referencing it:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:15:00 [seconds_ago] => 1275.3669655323 [data_type] => power [unit] => kW [value] => 0.059038 ) [1] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.73035812378 [data_type] => AC Energy (+) A [unit] => kWh [value] => 0.002 ) [2] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.66972780228 [data_type] => AC Energy (+) B [unit] => kWh [value] => 0.001 ) [3] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.69577527046 [data_type] => AC Energy (+) C [unit] => kWh [value] => 1491.76475 ) [4] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.78512835503 [data_type] => AC Energy (-) A [unit] => kWh [value] => 41.6215 ) [5] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.49988245964 [data_type] => AC Energy (-) B [unit] => kWh [value] => 134.34525 ) [6] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.56096410751 [data_type] => AC Energy (-) C [unit] => kWh [value] => 0 ) [7] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.54191684723 [data_type] => AC Energy A [unit] => kWh [value] => -41.6185 ) [8] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.4393093586 [data_type] => AC Energy B [unit] => kWh [value] => -134.34475 ) [9] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.52092242241 [data_type] => AC Energy C [unit] => kWh [value] => 1491.76625 ) [10] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.3975083828 [data_type] => AC Power A [unit] => kW [value] => -0.001582 ) [11] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.50329494476 [data_type] => AC Power B [unit] => kW [value] => -2.9E-5 ) [12] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.39441418648 [data_type] => AC Power C [unit] => kW [value] => 0.060649 ) [13] => Array ( [time] => 2013-09-19 00:15:43 [seconds_ago] => 14905232.37968 [data_type] => AC Watt Hours [unit] => Wh [value] => 0 ) [14] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.674295187 [data_type] => Apparent Power A [unit] => kVA [value] => 0.001691 ) [15] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.52429628372 [data_type] => Apparent Power B [unit] => kVA [value] => 9.3E-5 ) [16] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.56830334663 [data_type] => Apparent Power C [unit] => kVA [value] => 0.067142 ) [17] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.64755892754 [data_type] => Energy Apparent [unit] => kWh [value] => 1855.07525 ) [18] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.45766568184 [data_type] => Energy Apparent A [unit] => kWh [value] => 60.18575 ) [19] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.75435805321 [data_type] => Energy Apparent B [unit] => kWh [value] => 146.94025 ) [20] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.58755683899 [data_type] => Energy Apparent C [unit] => kWh [value] => 1647.94875 ) [21] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.62746334076 [data_type] => Energy Reactive [unit] => kWh [value] => -609.10125 ) [22] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.60714936256 [data_type] => Energy Reactive A [unit] => kWh [value] => 35.615 ) [23] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.41941714287 [data_type] => Energy Reactive B [unit] => kWh [value] => 55.14325 ) [24] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.47503495216 [data_type] => Energy Reactive C [unit] => kWh [value] => -699.862 ) [25] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.47842907906 [data_type] => Power Factor A [unit] => pf [value] => -0.00935 ) [26] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.48141813278 [data_type] => Power Factor B [unit] => pf [value] => -0.00311 ) [27] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.75786519051 [data_type] => Power Factor C [unit] => pf [value] => 0.00903 ) [28] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.70001840591 [data_type] => Power Reactive [unit] => kVAR [value] => -0.028296 ) [29] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.56455540657 [data_type] => Power Reactive A [unit] => kVAR [value] => 0.000598 ) [30] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.76123142242 [data_type] => Power Reactive B [unit] => kVAR [value] => -8.9E-5 ) [31] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.70475888252 [data_type] => Power Reactive C [unit] => kVAR [value] => -0.028806 ) [32] => Array ( [data_type] => demand today [unit] => kWh [value] => 0.707 ) [33] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.35778808594 [data_type] => generation [unit] => kWh [value] => 1421.3425 ) [34] => Array ( [data_type] => generation today [unit] => kWh [value] => 0.707 ) [35] => Array ( [time] => 2011-05-13 15:40:07 [seconds_ago] => 89153768.815151 [data_type] => net generation [unit] => kWh [value] => -54567 ) [36] => Array ( [time] => 2011-05-05 20:41:15 [seconds_ago] => 89826900.386709 [data_type] => predicted power [unit] => kW [value] => 8.8158451675 ) [37] => Array ( [time] => 2011-05-05 20:41:15 [seconds_ago] => 89826900.386604 [data_type] => predicted power [unit] => kW [value] => 8.8158451675 ) [38] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.82890295982 [data_type] => reactive power [unit] => kVAR [value] => 0 ) [39] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 375.8258600235 [data_type] => received power [unit] => kW [value] => 0 ) [40] => Array ( [time] => 2011-05-05 20:41:15 [seconds_ago] => 89826900.389256 [data_type] => temperature [unit] => Â°C [value] => 15.783333333333 ) [41] => Array ( [time] => 2012-10-09 07:00:00 [seconds_ago] => 44688975.37283 [data_type] => value [unit] => # [value] => 0 ) )
```

And the code as is outputs this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:15:00 [seconds_ago] => 1415.2291824818 [data_type] => power [unit] => kW [value] => 0.059038 ) [1] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.70772218704 [data_type] => AC Energy (+) A [unit] => kWh [value] => 0.002 ) [2] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.65894651413 [data_type] => AC Energy (+) B [unit] => kWh [value] => 0.001 ) [3] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.68033218384 [data_type] => AC Energy (+) C [unit] => kWh [value] => 1491.76475 ) [4] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.75129461288 [data_type] => AC Energy (-) A [unit] => kWh [value] => 41.6215 ) [5] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.47772955894 [data_type] => AC Energy (-) B [unit] => kWh [value] => 134.34525 ) [6] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.53927516937 [data_type] => AC Energy (-) C [unit] => kWh [value] => 0 ) [7] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.52115464211 [data_type] => AC Energy A [unit] => kWh [value] => -41.6185 ) [8] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.3775832653 [data_type] => AC Energy B [unit] => kWh [value] => -134.34475 ) [9] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.49898386002 [data_type] => AC Energy C [unit] => kWh [value] => 1491.76625 ) [10] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.30272579193 [data_type] => AC Power A [unit] => kW [value] => -0.001582 ) [11] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.48113703728 [data_type] => AC Power B [unit] => kW [value] => -2.9E-5 ) [12] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.29951524734 [data_type] => AC Power C [unit] => kW [value] => 0.060649 ) [13] => Array ( [time] => 2013-09-19 00:15:43 [seconds_ago] => 14905372.266252 [data_type] => AC Watt Hours [unit] => Wh [value] => 0 ) [14] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.66258645058 [data_type] => Apparent Power A [unit] => kVA [value] => 0.001691 ) [15] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.50254368782 [data_type] => Apparent Power B [unit] => kVA [value] => 9.3E-5 ) [16] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.54574537277 [data_type] => Apparent Power C [unit] => kVA [value] => 0.067142 ) [17] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.6393969059 [data_type] => Energy Apparent [unit] => kWh [value] => 1855.07525 ) [18] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.42687487602 [data_type] => Energy Apparent A [unit] => kWh [value] => 60.18575 ) [19] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.7258336544 [data_type] => Energy Apparent B [unit] => kWh [value] => 146.94025 ) [20] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.56782674789 [data_type] => Energy Apparent C [unit] => kWh [value] => 1647.94875 ) [21] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.61093878746 [data_type] => Energy Reactive [unit] => kWh [value] => -609.10125 ) [22] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.59347748756 [data_type] => Energy Reactive A [unit] => kWh [value] => 35.615 ) [23] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.32574605942 [data_type] => Energy Reactive B [unit] => kWh [value] => 55.14325 ) [24] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.44656801224 [data_type] => Energy Reactive C [unit] => kWh [value] => -699.862 ) [25] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.45034480095 [data_type] => Power Factor A [unit] => pf [value] => -0.00935 ) [26] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.45925021172 [data_type] => Power Factor B [unit] => pf [value] => -0.00311 ) [27] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.72936868668 [data_type] => Power Factor C [unit] => pf [value] => 0.00903 ) [28] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.68556404114 [data_type] => Power Reactive [unit] => kVAR [value] => -0.028296 ) [29] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.54261255264 [data_type] => Power Reactive A [unit] => kVAR [value] => 0.000598 ) [30] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.73253774643 [data_type] => Power Reactive B [unit] => kVAR [value] => -8.9E-5 ) [31] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.68865466118 [data_type] => Power Reactive C [unit] => kVAR [value] => -0.028806 ) [32] => Array ( [data_type] => demand today [unit] => kWh [value] => 0.707 ) [33] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.20262622833 [data_type] => generation [unit] => kWh [value] => 1421.3425 ) [34] => Array ( [data_type] => generation today [unit] => kWh [value] => 0.707 ) [35] => Array ( [time] => 2011-05-13 15:40:07 [seconds_ago] => 89153908.7698 [data_type] => net generation [unit] => kWh [value] => -54567 ) [36] => Array ( [time] => 2011-05-05 20:41:15 [seconds_ago] => 89827040.274846 [data_type] => predicted power [unit] => kW [value] => 8.8158451675 ) [37] => Array ( [time] => 2011-05-05 20:41:15 [seconds_ago] => 89827040.274708 [data_type] => predicted power [unit] => kW [value] => 8.8158451675 ) [38] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.78152966499 [data_type] => reactive power [unit] => kVAR [value] => 0 ) [39] => Array ( [time] => 2014-03-10 12:30:00 [seconds_ago] => 515.77783679962 [data_type] => received power [unit] => kW [value] => 0 ) [40] => Array ( [time] => 2011-05-05 20:41:15 [seconds_ago] => 89827040.277765 [data_type] => temperature [unit] => Â°C [value] => 15.783333333333 ) [41] => Array ( [time] => 2012-10-09 07:00:00 [seconds_ago] => 44689115.258793 [data_type] => value [unit] => # [value] => 0 ) )


powerAC Energy (+) AAC Energy (+) BAC Energy (+) CAC Energy (-) AAC Energy (-) BAC Energy (-) CAC Energy AAC Energy BAC Energy CAC Power AAC Power BAC Power CAC Watt HoursApparent Power AApparent Power BApparent Power CEnergy ApparentEnergy Apparent AEnergy Apparent BEnergy Apparent CEnergy ReactiveEnergy Reactive AEnergy Reactive BEnergy Reactive CPower Factor APower Factor BPower Factor CPower ReactivePower Reactive APower Reactive BPower Reactive Cdemand todaygenerationgeneration todaynet generationpredicted powerpredicted powerreactive powerreceived powertemperaturevalue
```

It looks to me that it gives me the value from that object entitled "data_type" but I 'm trying to figure out how reference one of the arrays instead of printing out all of them.

Comment: Well... what does the JSON look like?  All JSON doesn't share key's to use.  The reference you `print_r` out should give you a hint as to the keys that are being used to help with your loop.

Comment: You got some code there, which part of it is not working? Can you say exactly what you want and what you're getting? What does $string look like when you dump it?

Comment: `json_decode($json, TRUE);` will return a multidimensional array, so what are the objects we are talking about?

Comment: Looking at the JSON from the `file_get_contents`, you just a `foreach($string as $data)` and access each element with `$data['time']`, etc...

Comment: I think it is $value->data_type instead of $value['data_type']

Comment: @AlexSorinDachin you would be wrong ^^ The `json_decode($var, true)` decodes it in to an array rather than `stdObject`

Comment: @AlexSorinDachin no, the result is an associative array not an object in this case. OP: why don't you look at the results of your `print_r` (share them maybe) - it should show you how to access specific information

Comment: If you do not know the keys to an array then think about using the 'array current pointer' functions. See the manual: ['current' - check out 'Also' functions](http://uk3.php.net/current). These allow you to go through arrays without knowing anything about keys or values. All the iterators / foreach are built on them.

Comment: @RyanVincent or use [`array_keys`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to build the header information and then subsequently use that result to pull out the individual results for each row....

Comment: _For your edit_: To access each one individually, it would be based on numerical keys, so `$string[0]` would be the first, `$string[1]` the second, etc...

Comment: @Jon when I do that I get an "array to string" error. I also try using something like you suggested earlier. When I put in the code `$data['time_format']` with the foreach loop as `foreach($string as $data)` I get the same result where it lists the data_format of all the objects. I try using the numerical references in the array ([1], [2], [3]) but I get an "Undefined offset" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference an individual object in the $string array by using it's index such as $string[0].

*Edit*

If you wanted to group the objects by their data_type as separate arrays you can use the following;

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('http://application.deckmonitoring.com/data/latest.json?target_type=node&target_id=1&token=12345678901234567890');

    $string = json_decode($json, true);


    $power_type_objects = array();

    foreach ($string as $key => $value) {
        $power_type_objects[$value['data_type']][] = $string[$key];
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($power_type_objects); # for reference
    echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Which would give the following output:

> ```
> [power] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => Array
>             (
>                 [time] => 2014-03-10 14:15:00
>                 [seconds_ago] => 1890.1586380005
>                 [data_type] => power
>                 [unit] => kW
>                 [value] => 0.059942
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [AC Energy (+) A] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => Array
>             (
>                 [time] => 2014-03-10 14:30:00
>                 [seconds_ago] => 990.66510391235
>                 [data_type] => AC Energy (+) A
>                 [unit] => kWh
>                 [value] => 0.002
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [AC Energy (+) B] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => Array
>             (
>                 [time] => 2014-03-10 14:30:00
>                 [seconds_ago] => 990.61706137657
>                 [data_type] => AC Energy (+) B
>                 [unit] => kWh
>                 [value] => 0.001
>             )
>
>     )
> ```
>
> ....

Comment: that actually looks like it fixed it. I think I'll be ok from here! Thanks!